# Tracking all DNS calls within a network

Tags: networking, domain-name-system

Is there a simple way to have multiple computers on a network access the Internet and the history, files accessed or domains tracked in a global log?

Obviously it's a privacy issue on a larger network, but mostly for now a concern for home computer use with children and monitoring/blocking/directing their use safely and monitoring where bandwidth is being used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your children are not going to bypass your DNS setup,
I would recommend setting up [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com) access.

Here is a **HowToGeek** reference for the purpose: [Protect Your Kids Online Using Open DNS](http://blogs.howtogeek.com/mysticgeek/2008/08/07/protect-your-kids-online-with-any-os-using-open-dns/).

---

Handling covert redirection -- when that is a concern.
Login to OpenDNS, click through

- **Dashboard**,

  - **Settings**,

    - **Advanced Settings**, and,

      - Uncheck **Enable typo correction**.
      - Apply
      - [while you are here, checkout other controls available too]
- I have typically left this settings ON
- It is more important to check what your browser does on lookup failures

Comment: I'm already using OpenDNS which is great but doesn't allow for access to "restricted" content without pretty much disabling the service entirely temporarily. I simply want to see some kind of live graph of use or list of latest requested domains or something.

Comment: @peter, Oh, then you either need to try probing your DNS Cache or just setup a local DNS that will give you logs (think, Squid and company) and, probably also allow specific content-filtering (supported with public domain blacklists).

Answer (score 4):

You could try [opendns](http://www.opendns.com) to block based no dns queries, but it has [other privacy concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDNS#Privacy_issues.2C_conflicts_and_covert_redirection)...

As a better solution I will try a proxy (like squid) and blacklists/whitelists or applicatons like [dansguardian](http://dansguardian.org/).

Answer (score 0):

if you run your own local bind DNS server, you can turn on query logging. However, this will not tell you that someone went to http://foo.bar.com/dirty_pictures/blah/blah. It will simply show the request for foo.bar.com

Answer (score 0):

If you want more than just URL filtering (OpenDNS is a good choice here as a couple of others have already mentioned), then running a local [proxy server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) may fit your needs.  This is a little more technically challenging, but should allow you to combine OpenDNS while allowing you to do additional filtering and full logging or URL's accessed.

[Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) is a popular, open source, option but there are others as well.  If you modify your firewall to only allow the proxy server outbound http/https access, then it will be more difficult to circumvent the proxy.